# Populating a JTable row using a 2D array (using arr[i] instead of arr[i][j])

Tags: java, jtable

It is possible to populate a row in a JTable (named tblCustomers) by using a 2D String array (named data - containing data from a database table) as follows:

```
DefaultTableModel customerModel = (DefaultTableModel) tblCustomers.getModel();

for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {            
    customerModel.addRow(data[i]);   // here I've used data[i] even though it is a 2d array - and it works.         
}
```

Is it considered bad practice to populate the entire row in one iteration?

Comment: `data[i]` is not a 2D array; `data` is.

Comment: It was originally declared as a 2D array.  But you can populate the entire JTable row by calling just the first element like this.